# What does an integral sign with only an upper limit mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, self-learning

My course notes (Mathematics BSc, second year module on differential equations, unpublished) use expressions like
$$
\int^x\frac{b}{t}\text{d}t = b\ln(x).
$$
Is there an implied lower limit of $0$ (edit: $1$)?

Comment: In this case the implied lower limit is $t=1$, but this is really an indefinite integral

Comment: The lower limit cannot be zero. I'm guessing the lower limit is irrelevant as the r.h.s. is a function of $x$ and so this is just an indefinite integral.

Comment: I see it meaning that the contribution from the lower limit is a constant (independent of $x$), usually in the context it may be absorbed in another convenient constant. For instance, suppose $A$ is an unknown constant in $A \exp\left( \int\limits^x dt f(t) \right)$, any $x$ independent lower limit simply alters the constant $A$. Thus it is expedient to ignore the lower limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that, if a function $f(x)$ has anti-derivative $F(x)$, then:
$$\int_{a}^b f(x)\ dx=F(b)-F(a)$$
The notation implies such a lower limit, $a$, has been implicitly assumed, so that $F(a)=0$. So, in your given example, implied lower limit is $t=1$.
Basically they want to calculate the indefinite integral with arbitrary constant $C=0$.